# Nodejs jQuery needs jsdom

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, twitch

```
$.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/' + SLoppierKitty7, function(channel) {

if (channel["stream"] == null) { 
    var live ="no"

} else {

      var live ="yes"

}
```

that is my code but when i run it i get the following error

> E:\Sloppers bot\node_modules\jQuery\lib\node-jquery.js:5
>      window = require('jsdom').jsdom().createWindow();
>                                             ^
>
> TypeError: require(...).jsdom(...).createWindow is not a function
>           at create (E:\Sloppers bot\node_modules\jQuery\lib\node-jquery.js:5:39)
>           at E:\Sloppers bot\node_modules\jQuery\lib\node-jquery.js:9435:18
>           at Object. (E:\Sloppers bot\node_modules\jQuery\lib\node-jquery.js:9437:2)
>           at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
>           at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
>           at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
>           at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
>           at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
>           at require (module.js:384:17)
>           at Object. (E:\Sloppers bot\bot.js:2:9)

what do i do

this is for a bot i'm working

Comment: Is there a reason why want to use  jquery to request json data in nodejs?

Comment: Unless you have a need for jquery beyond $.getJSON, I would suggest to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/request which is a simpler wrapper around Node's native HTTP module.

Answer (score 13):

jquery 3.2.1, jsdom 10.1.0. It works.

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const { window } = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html>`);
const $ = require('jQuery')(window);

$('<h1>Hello</h1>').appendTo('body');
console.log($('h1').text());
```

Comment: Perfect! All of the code examples I was finding were for the outdated JSDOM syntax. Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 8):

I encountered the same problem, and it is OK now after I changed the package from `require('jQuery')` to `require('jquery')`. It seems that the later package ([jquery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery)) use a more recent version of jQuery than the former one ([jQuery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jQuery)).

Comment: that does not help.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue, and while debugging I came to know about something new.

When you do -

```
npm install jQuery
```

It installs the jQuery version 1.7.4 to your project.

And when you do -

```
npm install jquery
```

It installs the jQuery version 3.2.1 to your project.

[image]

The difference between both the command is just the uppercase **Q**. So if you are getting this error then you are probably using the old version of jQuery.

You can read more about the first command (the old version) [here](https://jquery.com/download/) and about the second command [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does. jQuery expects the 'window' to be there, which is normally a browser-only object. As such, the window needs to be simulated. That is what jsdom does.

After including jsdom (`npm install jsdom`):

```
// Load jsdom, and create a window.
var jsdom = require("jsdom").jsdom;
var doc = jsdom();
var window = doc.defaultView;

// Load jQuery with the simulated jsdom window.
$ = require('jquery')(window);
```

See the jsdom documentation for more information:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom

Comment: is jsdom in the node_modules directory, or anywhere else where it can be loaded with 'require' ?

Comment: it's in node_modules

Comment: remove line 5. It's still including jQuery the wrong way.

Comment: This is getting a bit hard to debug. Is it possible that you are using an quite old version of jQuery, that's still expecting an older version of jsdom?

Answer (score 0):

nothing worked for me from here,

my jquery version:3.2.1

jsdom version: 10.1.0
found a solution finally:

```
var myHtmlString = 'akkadsf lakuseh alhf lasudfa ls<p></p>';

function jQuery(doc){
    const jsdom = require("jsdom");
    const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
    const { window } = new JSDOM();
    const JQ = require("jquery")(window)(`<html>${doc || ''}</html>`);
}
var $ = jQuery;
// my html string:
var text = $(myHtmlString).text();
```

Comment: still not work for me : `TypeError: $.getJSON is not a function`