# "TypeError: jsdom.jsdom is not a function" with paper-node.js in npm paper module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, typeerror, jsdom

I have installed [webppl-agents](https://github.com/agentmodels/webppl-agents) library (along with [webppl](https://github.com/probmods/webppl) and [webppl-dp](https://github.com/stuhlmueller/webppl-dp)) and am trying to run the command line test, but I'm running into some trouble. It appears there is a dependency issue with jsdom from the npm paper module [(1)](https://github.com/rstacruz/jsdom-global/issues/22) [(2)](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/942) [(3)](https://github.com/davidpadbury/node-highcharts/issues/10) [(4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37239690/nodejs-jquery-needs-jsdom), but I haven't been able to get a complete handle on the issue at this point.

Does anybody know  what's going on here? Do I just need to use a newer version of paper?

```
 PS C:\Users\user\.webppl\node_modules\webppl-agents> webppl --require webppl-dp --require . tests/tests.wppl
C:\Users\user\.webppl\node_modules\webppl-agents\node_modules\paper\dist\paper-node.js:10835
        document = jsdom.jsdom('<html><body></body></html>'),
                         ^

TypeError: jsdom.jsdom is not a function
    at new <anonymous> (C:\Users\user\.webppl\node_modules\webppl-agents\node_modules\paper\dist\paper-node.js:10835:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\.webppl\node_modules\webppl-agents\node_modules\paper\dist\paper-node.js:33:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)

    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\.webppl\node_modules\webppl-agents\src\visualization\gridworld.js:1:75)
```

Answer (score 4):

There has been some breaking changes recently. The following way of initializing `jsodm`, `document` and `window` fixed it for me:

```
import jsdom from 'jsdom';  
const {JSDOM} = jsdom;  
const {document} = (new JSDOM('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>')).window;  
global.document = document;  
global.window = document.defaultView;
```